# Remove specific WooCommerce shipping methods depending on states

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I came across the code below which looks like it should do what I want. Upon testing, however, it's not working.

We need to get rid of 2nd day air shipping in certain states. For example, we are located in Pennsylvania, and if someone is buying from there, we don't want that option to show.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'unset_ups_shipping_rates_for_specific_states' , 10, 2 );
function unset_ups_shipping_rates_for_specific_states( $rates, $package ) {
    // Setup an array of states that do not allow UPS Shipping 2nd Day Air. As of 10/18/2015 we added 3 days ground too.
    $excluded_states = array( 'FL','AL','KY','LA','MS','TN','GA','SC','NC','KY','DC','VA','AR','CT','DE','IL','IN','KS','MA','ME','MD','MN','MI','MO','NH','NJ','NY','OH','OK','PA','RI','TX','VT','WV','WI' );
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package ) {
        if( in_array( $package, $excluded_states ) ) :
            unset( $rates['sups:02:0'] ); // Unset 2-Day Air
            unset( $rates['ups:02'] );
            unset( $rates['sups:12:0'] ); // Unset 3-Day Select too
            unset( $rates['ups:12'] );
        else:
            unset( $rates['sups:03:0'] ); // Unset Ground
            unset( $rates['ups:03'] );
        endif;
    }
    // Return what's left of the $rates array
    return $rates;
}
```

How can I make this code work to unset specific shipping methods based on states?

Edit: Using Aztec's answer, I did a var_dump($rates) since it's not working and got:

```
array(2) {
["UPS-Ground"]=> object(WC_Shipping_Rate)#1486 (6) {
["id"]=> string(10) "UPS-Ground"
["label"]=> string(10) "UPS Ground"
["cost"]=> string(5) "11.60"
["taxes"]=> array(0) { }
["method_id"]=> string(20) "easypostshippingtool"
["meta_data":"WC_Shipping_Rate":private]=> array(0) { }
}
["UPS-2ndDayAir"]=> object(WC_Shipping_Rate)#1514 (6) {
["id"]=> string(13) "UPS-2ndDayAir"
["label"]=> string(13) "UPS 2ndDayAir"
["cost"]=> string(5) "23.31"
["taxes"]=> array(0) { }
["method_id"]=> string(20) "easypostshippingtool"
["meta_data":"WC_Shipping_Rate":private]=> array(0) { }
}
}
```

Do you think that easypostshippingtool is interfering with the solution? Also, I'm not sure what the #1486 is. It comments out the code if i put it in a text editor.

Answer (score 3):

Instead you should use directly the **`$package`** argument provided in your hooked function to get the customer destination state this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_rates_for_specific_states', 10, 2 );
function shipping_rates_for_specific_states( $rates, $package ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    # Setup an array of states that do not allow UPS Shipping 2nd Day Air. 
    # As of 10/18/2015 we added 3 days ground too.
    $excluded_states = array(
        'FL','AL','KY','LA','MS','TN','GA','SC','NC','KY',
        'DC','VA','AR','CT','DE','IL','IN','KS','MA','ME',
        'MD','MN','MI','MO','NH','NJ','NY','OH','OK','PA',
        'RI','TX','VT','WV','WI'
    );

    $destination_state = $package['destination']['state'];

    if( in_array( $destination_state, $excluded_states ) ) {
        unset( $rates['sups:02:0'] ); // Unset 2-Day Air
        unset( $rates['ups:02'] );
        unset( $rates['sups:12:0'] ); // Unset 3-Day Select too
        unset( $rates['ups:12'] );
    } else {
        unset( $rates['sups:03:0'] ); // Unset Ground
        unset( $rates['ups:03'] );
    }*/

    return $rates;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce from 2.6.x to 3.0+ and should work with your custom rates.

> **You will need to refresh shipping cached data:** disable, save and enable, save related shipping methods for the current shipping zone, in woocommerce shipping settings.

---

Related answers: [Tiered Shipping with multiple Shipping rates options and prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274394/tiered-shipping-with-multiple-shipping-rates-options-and-prices)

Comment: LoicTheAztec, unfortunately I'm still getting 2nd day air to show up for excluded states in the array. Is it possible there's something interfering? I can't seem to figure it out. 

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I did a var_dump on $destination_state and got: string(0) ""

Also, my client is using this altered "Easy Post Shipping Plugin". Maybe this is interfering? I did a var dump on $rates. I put it in my question.

Comment: It just outputs products I have and their information, such as description, creation date, ect. nothing on shipping.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @snippet       Only ship to PA WooCommerce 2.1+
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=309
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 2.6.14
 */

function bbloomer_only_ship_to_pa( $rates, $package ) {
global $woocommerce;
$excluded_states = array( 'AL','AK','AS','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','DC','FL','FM','GA','GU','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA','KS','KY','LA','ME','MH','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND','MP','OH','OK','OR','PW','PR','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UM','UT','VT','VA','VI','WA','WV','WI','WY' );
if( in_array( WC()->customer->shipping_state, $excluded_states ) ) {
    $rates = array();
}
return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_only_ship_to_pa', 10, 2 );
```

with this code you can only ship selected states.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'xa_show_shipping_method_based_on_state', 10, 2 );

function xa_show_shipping_method_based_on_state( $available_shipping_methods, $package ) {

    $states_list = array( 'AK', 'HI', 'PR', 'GU', 'AS', 'VI', 'UM' );

    $eligible_services_for_states_list  =   array(
            'wf_shipping_usps:flat_rate_box_priority',
            'wf_shipping_usps:flat_rate_box_express',
            'wf_shipping_usps:D_FIRST_CLASS',
            'wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL',
            'wf_shipping_usps:D_STANDARD_POST',
            'wf_shipping_usps:D_MEDIA_MAIL',
            'wf_shipping_usps:D_LIBRARY_MAIL',
            'wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL',
            'wf_shipping_usps:I_EXPRESS_MAIL',
            'wf_shipping_usps:I_PRIORITY_MAIL',
            'wf_shipping_usps:I_GLOBAL_EXPRESS',
            'wf_shipping_usps:I_FIRST_CLASS',
            'wf_shipping_usps:I_POSTCARDS',         
        );

    // Basically, below code will reset shipping services if the shipping
    // state is other than defined states_list.
    if ( !in_array(WC()->customer->shipping_state, $states_list) ) {
        foreach ( $eligible_services_for_states_list as &$value ) {
            unset( $available_shipping_methods[$value] );       
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

[got from here](https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-filter-shipping-methods-based-on-state/)